# Image Storage in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, rest

I am developing android application with restFul webservice.anyone can tell that How all Android WebApplication developers Maintaining Images With common Database.

**1)Will  they storing  only ImagePath on DataBase?**

**2)will they Storing Image on DataBase?**

Answer (score 0):

I am using a pre-populated database shipped with in the apk. Image's file name is written in the database table and Images are in drawables folder.

So in my case i read the file name from the database and get the image from the drawable folder.

You can use this method.

Put the image url-path into the database.

Comment: but i am developing Web Application.so lot of images have to upload by different users.then how can I?

Comment: if every app having theirs own database,then your idea will be ok.but all App have to access one database.then how it will be possible?

Comment: I don't say use my pre-populated database approach. Just put the image path in your database and use this path (URL/URI) to access the image on the server.